# How to add a loop to my python guessing game?

Tags: python

So I am very new to python as I spend most of my time using HTML and CSS. I am creating a small project to help me practice which is a number guessing game:

```
guess_number = (800)

guess = int(input('Please enter the correct number in order to win: '))

if guess != guess_number:
    print('Incorrect number, you have 2 more attempts..')

    guess2 = int(input('Please enter the correct number in order to win: '))

    if guess2 != guess_number:
        print('Incorrect number, you have 1 more attempts..')

        guess2 = int(input('Please enter the correct number in order to win: '))

    if guess2 != guess_number:
        print()
        print('Sorry you reached the maximum number of tries, please try again...')

    else:
        print('That is correct...')


elif guess == guess_number:
    print('That is correct...')
```

So my code currently works, when run, but I would prefer it if it looped instead of me having to put multiple if and else statements which makes the coding big chunky. I know there are about a million other questions and examples that are similar but I need a solution that follows my coding below.

Thanks.

Comment: In the future (since there is already an answer..) please make attempts to answer your own question. You could very easily google python loops and figure this out

Comment: Like I said in my question: I know there are about a million other questions and examples that are similar but I need a solution that follows my coding below.

Comment: @pythonisking that will *always be the case*; except for the most trivial, well-known exercises, you will not find somebody doing exactly what you are. One of the key skills of programming (/life in general) is taking general techniques and applying them to specific problems. If you can't take general ideas about looping and counting and apply them to such a simple problem, you're sunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a counter that holds the number of additionally allowed answers:

```
guess_number = 800
tries_left = 3

while tries_left > 0:
    tries_left -= 1
    guess = int(input('Please enter the correct number in order to win: '))
    if guess == guess_number:
        print('That is correct...')
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect number, you have ' + str(tries_left if tries_left > 0 else 'no')  + ' more attempts..')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many times you need to loop beforehand, use a `while` loop.

```
correct_guess = False
while not correct_guess:
    # get user input, set correct_guess as appropriate
```

If you do know how many times (or have an upper bound), use a `for` loop.

```
n_guesses = 3
correct_guess = False
for guess_num in range(n_guesses):
    # set correct_guess as appropriate

    if correct_guess:
        # terminate the loop
        print("You win!")
        break
else:
    # if the for loop does not break, the else block will run
    print("Out of guesses!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error, `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` if you go with the answer you have selected. Add `str()` to convert the tries left to a string. See below:

```
guess_number = 800
tries_left = 3

while tries_left > 0:
    tries_left -= 1
    guess = int(input('Please enter the correct number in order to win: '))
    if guess == guess_number:
        print('That is correct...')
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect number, you have ' + (str(tries_left) if tries_left > 0 else 'no')  + ' more attempts..')
```

Comment: Hi, yes I am aware with that error and I have fixed it. I edited the original answer by L3viathan but I am waiting for someone to assess it. The fix would be: print('Incorrect number, you have ', + tries_left if tries_left > 0 else 'no', ' more attempts..')

Comment: Ok, yep. That also fixes the problem. Thanks for the info! Do you happen to know why the comma fix also worked? I am trying to learn more as I am new to python too. I am having a hard time finding the documentation on how it works since I don't know what that approach is called.